# Core Data sum of all instances attribute

Tags: ios, core-data

Using **Core Data**, I encountered a problem. I have an entity "Movement" with an attribute "amount". How do I make the sum of all the "amount" of all instances? I'd like to understand how to use `NSExpressionDescription`, but it's good enough `NSSet`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Having a managedObjectContext:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = ...
```

We create a fetch request with return type dictionary:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Movement class])];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Then we create an expression description to calculate the sum:

```
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = @"sumOfAmounts";
expressionDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;
```

Set the request properties to fetch:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];
```

We could also set a predicate if we want.

And last we execute the request and get an array containing a dictionary with one key(@"sumOfAmounts") and its value is a NSNumber with the sum of amounts.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (result == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSNumber *sumOfAmounts = [[result objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"sumOfAmounts"];
}
```

Cheers

Comment: @e1985 one question please: I to calculate the sum of a single instance use: `NSNumber *sum = [fund valueForKeyPath:@"fund_relativeMovement.@sum.amount"];` and I would use the same mechanism that you have written, for this, too. just that I do not know how to set up an instance as an entity before the expression. Thanks!

Comment: Love this! How would I use this to run against a sorted fetchRequest? My table has 2 sections, each with sets of values. I want the unique total of each section.

Comment: Whether this works depends on the type of persistent store used. While it does work when backed by SQLite, I couldn't get it to work with `NSInMemoryStoreType`.
If you are getting an `[<NSDictionaryMapNode ...> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @sum.` exception, this can be a sign that your persistent store doesn't support this feature.

Comment: @TimBodeit, I did not test it with NSInMemoryStoreType, but I guess you are right. In the past I found issues with different types CoreData persistent stores. In my case, it was the other way around: something that was working in-memory in a test wasn't with SQLite. I ended up using SQLite as well in the test to get the same behaviour as in actual production code.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a **Swift** example of summing a managed object's attribute using `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription`. The example assumes that the managed object is named **`Movement`** and the attribute to sum is  **`amount`**.

**Example:**

```
 func sumAmount() -> Double {
    var amountTotal : Double = 0

    // Step 1:
    // - Create the summing expression on the amount attribute.
    // - Name the expression result as 'amountTotal'.
    // - Assign the expression result data type as a Double.

    let expression = NSExpressionDescription()
    expression.expression =  NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")])
    expression.name = "amountTotal";
    expression.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.doubleAttributeType

    // Step 2:
    // - Create the fetch request for the Movement entity.
    // - Indicate that the fetched properties are those that were
    //   described in `expression`.
    // - Indicate that the result type is a dictionary.

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Movement")
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expression]
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType

    // Step 3:
    // - Execute the fetch request which returns an array.
    // - There will only be one result. Get the first array
    //   element and assign to 'resultMap'.
    // - The summed amount value is in the dictionary as
    //   'amountTotal'. This will be summed value.

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let resultMap = results[0] as! [String:Double]
        amountTotal = resultMap["amountTotal"]!
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Error when summing amounts: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return amountTotal
}
```

---

**Additional Discussion of Steps:**

**Step 1** - Create an **`NSExpressionDescription`** variable. This `NSExpressionDescription` indicates what type of function is applied to the arguments. The **sum** function is being applied to the **amount** attribute.

```
expression.expression =  NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", 
    arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")])
```

Notice that the **arguments** parameter is an *array*. You can pass different types of expressions in the array, but, in our case we only want the `amount` attribute.

**Step 2** - The fetch request is established here. Notice that the result type is specified as a dictionary: `fetchRequest.resultType = NSAttributeType.DictionaryResultType`. In Step 3 we will use the `expression.name` value of `amountTotal` as the key to access the summed value.

**Step 3** - We execute the fetch request and returned will be a one element array. The element will be a dictionary which we caste to `[String:Double]`: `let resultMap = results[0] as! [String:Double]`. The dictionary's value is a Double because in Step 1 we indicated that the `expression.expressionResultType` would be a Double.

Finally, we access the sum by calling the dictionary value associated with the `amountTotal` key: `resultMap["amountTotal"]!`

---

**References:**

[NSExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSExpression) and [NSExpressionDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSExpressionDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSExpressionDescription)

Comment: thanks for the elaboration, this should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a [fetch for specific values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) and supply a [NSExpressionDescription with a `sum:` function.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:)

When you execute the fetch you get a one element array containing a dictionary whose keys match the expression descriptions and whose values are the results of the expressions. In this case, you would get a `sum` key whose value would be the sum of the attributes given the expression.