# Core Data, Get Sum Of Certain Boolean Value Attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, attributes

I'm logging a `Core Data` attribute "passed" (Boolean value)

```
for (Circuit *object in self.distributionBoard.circuits) {
        NSLog(@"Core Data Value =  %d", object.passed);


    }
```

This logs fine. What's the most efficient way to count the number of times the saved boolean value `== 1`?

Using `NSFetchReques` or `NSExpression` did not yield the desired result so far.  Looked here:  [Core Data sum of all instances attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822618/core-data-sum-of-all-instances-attribute) and similar, with the usual searches

Comment: That answer you link to describes a method you can use to get what you're asking for. If it didn't work, what problem(s) did you have?

Comment: `sumOfAmounts` always returns zero. In core data Class = "Circut", attribute = "passed".  fetch request is`[Circuit class]`,  `expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.passed"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your property is a boolean, you can make it a lot simpler than the methods described in that answer. Use a predicate to match the value of `passed` and then get the count of the result instead of the fetched objects. Something like:

```
NSFetchRequest<Event *> *fetchRequest = MyEntity.fetchRequest;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"passed = true"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Then `count` has the number of instances where `passed` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, nice elegant solution