# CoreData rewards by sum of an attribute rather than individual records

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on an app that rewards users when they record a walk, bike ride or bus ride. They are rewarded after a distance reached per journey but I would like to reward them for the total (sum) distance they have recorded with the app using `CoreData`.

I have tried to look at other Stack Overflow questions on the same topic but have been unsuccessful so far

```
for journey in journeys where journey.distance > reward.distance {
         if earned == nil {
          earned = journey
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing what you are asking for. To check if sum of some elements is greater than some value it might be best to use `reduce` in swift. Something like the following:

```
private func checkRewardAchieved(_ reward: Reward, withJourneys journeys: [Journey]) -> Bool {
    return journeys.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.distance }) >= reward.distance
}
```

Here `journeys.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.distance })` will return a sum of all distances in your array. The sum is then compared to rewards `>= reward.distance` and result is either true or false.

It might be nice to compute the sum directly with core data though. To do so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323953/526828) looks promising.