# Iterate through Core Data with for loop?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to add all expenses that match a certain category in an expense tracker app.

```
        ForEach(fetchRequestExpense) { (expenselog: Expenses) in
                if category == expenselog.expenseCategory{
                    var sum += expenselog.expenseCost
                }
            }
        return sum
    }
```

This won't compile. Should I be using a for loop for this type of calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ForEach` is a dynamic view container for constructing SwiftUI views, for control flow you have to use regular swift `for/in`, like

```
var sum = 0.0
for expenselog in fetchRequestExpense {
    if category == expenselog.expenseCategory {
        sum += expenselog.expenseCost
    }
}
return sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use an `@sum` fetch request and dictionary result type:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequestresulttype/1506237-dictionaryresulttype

See this similar question:

[Core Data sum of all instances attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822618/core-data-sum-of-all-instances-attribute)